# Remove TableHeaderView separator

Tags: swift, tableview

I want to remove the separators in my TableHeaderView. Removing the separators in the storyboard or use UIColor.clear will not work.

How can I remove the separators in my TableHeaderView?

How I create my TableHeaderView:

```
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 70)
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.default
    searchBar.placeholder = ""
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchUsers.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    searchUsers.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchBar.frame.size.height)
```

[image]